# How to extend data-model with new method?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize to store and save data to a database.

```
var sequelize = require('../database.js').sequelize,
    Sequelize = require('../database.js').Sequelize;

User = sequelize.define('user', {
    authID:     Sequelize.STRING,
    name:       Sequelize.STRING,
});

User.prototype.createRider = () => {
    console.log('test');
};

module.exports = User;
```

I'm trying to extend the model with a new method to store a specific kind of user, but `User.prototype.createRider` doesn't work. What can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "expansion of models" section in [their documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/)

I believe you can use the classMethods object

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('foo', { /* attributes */}, {
classMethods: {
    createRider: function(){ return 'smth' }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define both instance and class methods on your Model, during the define.

Change your `sequelize.define` as follows:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {
    authID:     Sequelize.STRING,
    name:       Sequelize.STRING,
}, classMethods: {
    createRider: function() {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

You can then use the `classMethods` in the expected way:

```
User.createRider();
```

See the Sequelize documentation: [Model Definition](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/).